# MUI x datagrid how to use excel export worker

Tags: javascript, material-ui, web-worker, mui-x-data-grid

I'm using the datagrid in material ui with react to display data and generate an Excel export.

I want to use the option to use a web worker, but I cannot find an elaborate example how to do that. The documentation gives source code to an example worker file and says it needs to be accessible via an url. I'm using the "create react app" script template from facebook and I don't know how to make the worker file (from the example code) build to a standalone file that may be accessed via a url.

How can I do that?

Documentation: https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/export/#using-a-web-worker